# Change view on completion in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, view, swiftui, completionhandler

I have developed a view that manages three subviews: `login`, `register` and `confirm code`.

Now I'm developing a separate view that manages all the subviews after login successful. The idea is that after login with success the new is pushed and the old is popped.

I've tried with `NavigationLink` in the login subview but it seems that it doesn't like the `isActive` change in the rest response (ie in the completion).

Here is the code:

```
NavigationLink(
   destination: LoggedView(),
   isActive: self.$pushToLogged,
   label: {
                
   }
).hidden()
```

```
func login() {
    let lF = LoginServiceFacade()
    lF.loginMember(mobileNumber: mobileNumber, password: password, completion: {
        (response: LoginResponse?, error: ConnectionErrors?) in
            self.pushToLogged = true
    })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is quite a simple and understandable example of a possible way of doing so:

First provide a wrapping view that checks if you are logged in or not. Display the according view:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var isLoggedIn: Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        Group() {
            if self.isLoggedIn {
                Home(isLoggedIn: self.$isLoggedIn)
            } else {
                Login(isLoggedIn: self.$isLoggedIn)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then have your home view which can have whatever structure you want. I for e.g. choose a TabView:

```
struct Home: View {
    
    @Binding var isLoggedIn: Bool
    
    var body: some View {
        TabView {
            Example(subTitle: "First")
                .tabItem {
                    Image(systemName: "list.dash")
                    Text("First")
                }

            Example(subTitle: "Second")
                .tabItem {
                    Image(systemName: "square.and.pencil")
                    Text("Second")
                }
        }
    }
}

struct Example: View {
    
    @State var subTitle: String
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello World \(self.subTitle)")
    }
}
```

The login view with the completion:

```
struct Login: View {
    
    @Binding var isLoggedIn: Bool
    
    var myLogin: myLoginClass = myLoginClass()
    
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            self.myLogin.loginWithCompletion { isSucceeded in
                if isSucceeded {
                    self.isLoggedIn.toggle()
                }
            }
        }) {
            Text("Log me in")
        }
    }
}

class myLoginClass {
    // Completing method
    // Here would be your code that would "complete" true if successfully logged in or false if error

    // I'm just waiting to "simulate" the visual process
    func loginWithCompletion(completion: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) {
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2) {
            completion(true)
        }
    }
    
}
```

This produces this example:

[image: Example as gif]

Comment: I don't think you've answered the question: *Change view on __completion__ in SwiftUI*. I suggest you add an example how to change `isLoggedIn` in a completion handler.

Comment: Yes you are right. I was too focused on the description that I forgot the title.

Comment: I found the same answer in the previous topics and I used it for the home view (login, register and confirm code). But now I want to completely change the view on login response to have a cleaner code. In other words I don't want a home view that manages 15 subviews